# Is it possible to set Right Size All Columns Individually as default for all Finder windows all the time in column view?

Tags: finder

When I switch to column view in Finder, I want to have the column widths to 'Right Size All Columns Individually', 99.9% of the time.

The problem is that this setting goes back to the very narrow default everytime a new window is opened. How can I make my prefered setting the default?